# Is anyone allowed to attend a parish council meeting?

Tags: united-kingdom, law

I own an allotment in a different parish to the one I live in. I wanted to speak to the parish council that owns my allotment about my tennancy and the management of the allotments. I came along to a meeting after I was invited by the clerk. I was allowed to speak to five minutes... but then I was sent away because "I wasn't part of the parish so it does not concern me".

Is this the law? They said I strictly was not allowed to stay?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Certainly not, the public and press are legally allowed to attend any parish council meeting. Therefore by throwing you out for the reason given "You were not a member of the parish" is illegal. *However*, the meeting [can pass a resolution](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiH5vOrtdnUAhVBKVAKHdtGD18QFggtMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.swallowfieldpc.gov.uk%2Fdocs_statutory%2Fview.php%3Ffile%3DGuide%2520to%2520Public%2520Participation%2520at%2520Parish%2520Council%2520Meetings%2520March%25202015.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGC6SAt-Wn-TTjIu3QdBx1JJOgPxA) to exclude you for specific bills under certain conditions e.g.

> for specific items which need to be discussed in confidence, for example but not limited to staffing matters, financial details relating to individuals or tenders for contracts.

However you have *No legal right to speak at the meeting*, since that is a privilege reserved for elected parish councillors. However most councils will allow you to speak if you ask to, if you have trouble speaking you should *request a copy of the councils standing orders*, since most councils would have adopted a standing order of some sort allowing you to speak. The chairman should explain this process to you.

*[Source](https://www.cpalc.org.uk/q-what-are-town-and-parish-council-meetings-an-introduction)*